# Problem rooting Xperia E Dual

Tags: rooting, usb-debugging, flashtool

I am following the below post to root my Xperia E Dual.

> [How To Root Xperia E! Latest Update! (Locked Bootloader)*LINKS
>   UPDATED* NOOB
>   GUIDE!](http://forum.xda-developers.com/xperia-j-e/general/how-to-root-xperia-e-update-locked-t2409525)

In step 4 to install Framaroot APK we need to Check the option "Unknown sources" and "Usb dubugging" (in Developer options)

But when I am turning on the Developer option Flashtool is showing an message like below:

```
08/048/2014 01:48:38 - INFO  - Device connected with USB debugging off
08/048/2014 01:48:38 - INFO  - For 2011 devices line, be sure you are not in MTP mode
```

I have tried changing the Usb connection mode but problem is not resolved. Could you please help?

**Some info:**

Operating System Used to flash: Windows 8.1

Comment: Are platform tools updated to 33.x (34.x has some problems reportedly//did you change port and cable?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look for towelroot tr. It might work on your device. It is just an apk you can install and start. It uses a kernel vulnerability. Chances that it works are high if your firmware is older than june.

To your issue: did you enable (usb-)debugging mode? Its in developper options. If you do not see them in your settings, go to AboutDevice and hit build number 5 times quickly. It enables a (secret) menu in your settings where you can enable adb.

On some samsung devices you can change usb mode by typing *#0808# into your phone apk. Without hitting the call button, a service menu opens up immediately. Perhaps this works for your device too. Did you try to do adb shell or adb devices from your commandline?

New devices now usually ask for an ok on the device screen  before you can connect. Disconnect and connect again, watch out for this popup. Did you check the developper menu in settings? There you can also flush the known pc's and their settings. Allowing the popup to sow up again after connecting.

Comment: 1. Towelroot is not working for my device. 2. My problem is USB debugging mode is detected wrongly by the Flashtool software. When I am turning the USB debugging on then the Flashtool is detecting it as turned off.

Answer (score 0):

It could be the power of the actual USB ie, a laptop. Try running it on another PC. If nothing else, check cabling.